# Hosting a workflow in console application in .NET 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How I can host a workflow in a console application? I googled enough and didn't find any good sample.

Comment: I'm sure there must be samples out there....

Comment: Sigh.  The *template for a workflow console application* is 100% complete.  All you need to do is add the activities to the workflow.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised you can't find an example as most basic examples are done using a console application. For example this one.

The workflow runtime is independent of the kind of host so something like this works just fine in a console application or equally well in an ASP.NET or WPF application for that matter.

```
var workflow = new Workflow1();
workflow.FirstName = "Maurice";
workflow.LastName = "de Beijer";

var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow);
Console.WriteLine(result["Greeting"]);
```

Comment: I'm new to WF and I've a doubt with the above code snippet will that invoke a workflow or host a workflow? I want the workflow to be hosted in a separate process like a console application and from another console application(client) I'll invoke the workflow.

Comment: So you want to use a workflow service and interact with it through WCF? In that case you start with the WorkflowServiceHost and add a Receive activity to your workflow to receive WCF messages.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. WorkflowService is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like the following where 'FeedManager' is the console app, ProcessAllImports and ProcessAllExportFeeds are code or xaml activities. Its simple but works well.
Hope this helps...

```
class FeedManager
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FeedManager fm = new FeedManager();
        fm.Run(args);
    }

    private int Run(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessAllImports importProcess = new ProcessAllImports();
        List<Feed> importFeedSuccesses = new List<Feed>();
        List<Feed> importFeedsFailure =  new List<Feed>();

        ProcessAllExportFeeds exportProcess = new ProcessAllExportFeeds();
        List<Feed> exportFeedSuccesses = new List<Feed>();
        List<Feed> exportFeedsFailure = new List<Feed>();

        try
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> importFeedsArgs = new Dictionary<string, object> 
            { 
                { "FeedsSuccess", importFeedSuccesses }, 
                { "FeedsFailure", importFeedsFailure },
            };
            var importOutput = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(importProcess, importFeedsArgs);
            bool importSuccess = (bool)importOutput["Success"];
            importFeedSuccesses = (List<Feed>)importOutput["FeedsSuccess"];
            importFeedsFailure = (List<Feed>)importOutput["FeedsFailure"];

            IDictionary<string, object> exportFeedsArgs = new Dictionary<string, object> 
            { 
                { "FeedsSuccess", exportFeedSuccesses }, 
                { "FeedsFailure", exportFeedsFailure },
            };
            var exportOutput = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(exportProcess, exportFeedsArgs);
            bool exportSuccess = (bool)exportOutput["Success"];
            exportFeedSuccesses = (List<Feed>)exportOutput["FeedsSuccess"];
            exportFeedsFailure = (List<Feed>)exportOutput["FeedsFailure"];

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
```